# Beginner Python 3 syntax

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x

I have been writing a simple quiz with python but keep getting a "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement" in my Python GUI. Please help.

```
print("Welcome to my quiz!")
score = 0
question1 = str(input("What colour is a banana."))
if question.lower() == 'yellow':
    print("Correct. The answer is", question1)
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect. The answer is yellow, not", question1)
print score
```

Answer (score 8):

You've got a couple issues. First, `question` is not defined (line 4); that should be `question1`. Second, `print` is a function in Python 3, so your last line ought to be `print(score)`. Third, `input` already returns a string, so you don't need the `str` call. So line 3 ought to look like this:

```
question1 = input("What colour is a banana.")
```

Comment: There is no `raw_input` in python 3.

Comment: @PavelAnossov Oh, heck. That's what I get for posting on a Py3 question without Py3 installed. Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a more advanced version of your program but by using a list we can do it easier

```
    print("Welcome to my quiz!")
score = 0 
color = ['yellow']
question1 = str(input("What colour is a banana."))
if question1 == color[0]:
    print("Correct. The answer is", question1)
    score +=1
    print(score)
else:
    print("Incorrect. The answer is yellow, not", question1)
    
    print (score)
```